# What do the + numbers mean in a stack trace

Tags: c#

I am trying to track down an exception thrown in a c# web app I have created and was wondering if someome could tell me what the + numbers relate to on each line in the stack trace

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the offset from the start of the method, so the Exception is thrown 110 bytes (in IL) from the start of GetEmployee (which is not directly translatable to a line number due to compiling, jitting, inlining etc.)

Comment: What would be the best way to debug knowing the offset?